# What is the difference between SHA-3(Keccak) and previous generation SHA algorithms?

Tags: hash, algorithm-design, sha-1, sha-2, sha-3

SHA-1 and SHA-2 share the same structure and mathematical operation as their predecessors - SHA-0 and MD5.  Both SHA-0 and MD5 have been broken. This is one of the main reasons why SHA-1 is considered insecure and is being phased out for SHA-2.

NIST announced in 2007 a competition to produce the next generation NIST hash function: SHA-3.

What is the major difference in structure and mathematical operation between the previous SHA-1 and SHA-2 functions and SHA-3?

Comment: This question is too broad. There are many introductory resources about Keccak online.

Comment: Not sure I agree. The basic difference can be broken down to the high level construction chosen and the mathematical operations used in the round function. A good answer would not be long, especially if it linked to other questions/resources for the specifics.

Comment: I agree the question is too broad if you want to know about Keccak but I have not found much explanation with difference between SHA-3(Keccak) and previous generations SHAs.

Comment: Ok, so we expect something about sponge construction here, length extension attacks and SHAKE at the least.

Comment: Let’s simply try to get rid of some of the broadness of your question… ***could you please clarify what research you’ve done?*** See, we do expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking here, including searching this site for [tag:sha-1], [tag:sha-256], and [tag:sha-3] that might shed light on your question. At worst it will help you frame *“[a better question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)”*; at best it might even answer it.

Comment: Actually, I am reading a book - Cryptography and Network Security - William Stallings. I have not read all articles here. I just posted because I didn't found any alike question.

Wanted some better explanation of the article from experts here.
I will edit the questions to details later.

Comment: If you are happy with an answer, please click on the tick mark. Or else, specify what more is needed. Just don't sit idle without responding to answers.

Comment: sorry, I was expecting a better explanation and was busy lately due to exams. anyways i accepted your answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference is: All SHA-0, 1 & 2 and MD5 come under a class of algorithm called [Merkle–Damgård construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Damg%C3%A5rd_construction), while SHA-3 falls under [Sponge functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sponge_function).

[Merkle–Damgård construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Damg%C3%A5rd_construction) is a method of building collision-resistant cryptographic hash functions from collision-resistant one-way compression functions. 
[image: Merkle–Damgård construction]

And, [Sponge functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sponge_function) are a class of algorithms with finite internal state that take an input bit stream of any length and produce an output bit stream of any desired length.

[image: Sponge Function]

The main reason for the change is because a number of attacks were discovered for its predecessors, there was a fear that the very secure SHA-2 would be broken soon. So, to avoid that they chose Keccak as it was completely different from existing SHA algorithms and the AES.

Comment: Not to mention that MD5 (which was clearly broken) was also based on the Merkle-Damgård scheme). So, they were real suspicions that flaws would be found soon.

Comment: This is indeed the reason why the SHA-3 competition was started. I'm not sure that this is the main reason why Keccak was chosen though, and I did at least follow the mailinglist.

Comment: Note also a core difference: The sponge construction relies on a *permutation* whereas Merkle-Damgard relies on a one-way collision-resistant compression function.

Answer (score 14):

They are all hash functions. Apart from that, they are structurally quite different. The SHA family (SHA-0, SHA-1, and the SHA-2 functions such as SHA-256 and SHA-512) use the [Merkle-Damgård](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Damg%C3%A5rd_construction) construction, around an internal permutation which happens to be an extended Feistel network. Low-level primitives include boolean bitwise operations, and addition over 32-bit or 64-bit integers.

In SHA3, the structure is that of a [sponge function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sponge_function), which is quite different. Moreover, the inner permutation is not a Feistel network; low-level primitives are boolean bitwise operations over 64-bit words, but *not* additions. This avoidance of operations that involve carry propagation helps a lot with performance on hardware implementations (FPGA, ASIC).

Comment: I would put state truncation and shift operators in the similarities column, it's the sha2 fixed points that scare  me

Comment: The output sizes are identical (by design) to SHA-2. SHA-3 was created as a drop in replacement after all; it just differs internally.

Answer (score 8):

While Switch is right about the difference between Merkle–Damgård and Sponge constructions, I don't believe he is correct as to NIST's reasoning.

I happened to talk to a NIST cryptographer (John Kelsey) about this.  He indicated that they selected Keccak not because they distrust the SHA-2 design (Merkle–Damgård is provably secure if the compression function is collision-resistant, and we have no reason to doubt the SHA-2 compression functions). And it's not to get greater crypto-diversity (even though it does that; the designs of SHA-2 and SHA-3 are quite different).  Instead, John indicated that the most attractive thing they saw in Keccak was its flexibility.

While the sponge construction can be used to create a hash function, it can also be used to create other things, such as an XOF (Extensible Output Function; essentially as hash function with an arbitrary length output).  NIST has standardized SHAKE-128 and SHAKE-256 as SHA-3 based XOF's.  In addition, you can do other things with a sponge construction; it's quite possible that NIST will standardize those usages as well.

Comment: That's a bit strange. Skein seems to have this kind of flexibility as well, and that's certainly Merkle–Damgård. Furthermore, as it contains a 256 bit tweakable block cipher, it would be very useful to create a complete symmetric cryptosystem. That's why I supported it anyway. There are of course other considerations such as speed as well though.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, while Skein is fancy in design and implementation, you can actually do (nearly) everything that is possible with Skein equally well with Keccak and some other things as well (i.e. [you can use the sponge for AE](https://aezoo.compute.dtu.dk/doku.php?id=keyak)) and Keccak profited much more from the standardization because Intel will sooner or later make SHA-3 extensions (hopefully) and in hardware Keccak should beat Skein in speed, because of the bit permutations.